# write the out put on file

Tags: php

I am very new to php, and i have search and put together this script to convert text to csv and write the out put on the file.

```
      $File = "/var/apache2/htdocs/loginS/host.txt";
      $Handle = fopen($File,"r");
      $Content = fread ($Handle,filesize ($File));
       fclose($File);
       fclose($Handle);
       $Content = explode("\t", $Content);
       foreach($Content as $Value) {
                //echo $Value."|"; // till this line working 
       fwrite($save, $Value); 
       fclose($save); 
       }
```

the problem is when I try to write on the file. I got only one line.what is my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `fclose()` on the file in your loop that is writing records.  `fclose()` closes the file handle so it is no longer valid and cannot be written to.

Move `fclose($save);` after the `}` that ends the `foreach()` with your content.

Also, you could simplify things a bit by calling `$Content = file_get_contents($File);` since that is what you are doing in effect with `fread()`.  Also, since `$File` is just a string variable, calling `fclose()` on it is unnecessary and doesn't do anything.  You were correctly closing it by calling `fclose()` on `$Handle`.  But using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) will eliminate the need for both.  The only file you would need is the one you were writing to.

Here is an example using the [file()](http://php.net/file) function which reads each line of a file into an array.

```
$file    = '/var/apache2/htdocs/loginS/host.txt';
$content = file($file);

$save    = fopen('./out.csv', 'w+');

foreach($content as $line) {
    $line  = rtrim($line, "\r\n");  // remove the newline from $line
    $parts = explode("\t", $line);

    $lineCsv = implode('|', $parts); // or ',' ?
    fwrite($save, $lineCsv . "\n");  // write output to file
}

fclose($save);
```